# Dynamic Database System with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Please I am creating a database system for a group,using mysql and php.I am faced with some challenges,these are

1.I want to make the database system dynamic - thus where an administrator using the system would be able to add columns to a specific table from the front end without having to know something about mysql and php.

2.Also,I want the administrator who is ignorant of mysql and php, to be able to add tables to the database through the front end (PHP page).

3.With the aforementioned problems in (1 and 2), how would I make the columns added by the administrator appear on a form (php page) from the database, and how do I check for errors on the form.

Please these are instances to clarify what I have said.

a.What should I do to make a client add columns to an existing table in the database without any assistance from the technical team?

b.What should I do to make a client add tables to an existing database without help from technical team?

c.How do I output columns added by an administrator to a form and also check for errors on the form (php page) .

Any help is welcomed.Thank You

Comment: Do you know php? Do you know SQL how to add columns/rows? If yes, then whats the problem? You just have to programatically create many forms and check them for input errors and when the form is sent execute the code that this form wants, e.g. if user clicked on add column button, new form appeared where he types field type (int,varchar), length and name. In php you catch it something like this: `ALTER TABLE chosen_table ADD column VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;` where `chosen_table` and `varchar ( 255 )` are variables. But it may be hard and boring job :)

Comment: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model

Answer (score 1):

Well basically you can just write queries like `ALTER TABLE xxx ADD column VARCHAR(100)` etc. filling in the desired values from a form. This is, however, strongly discouraged. Not only would this mean your script would be able to execute queries which normally can only be executed by (mysql) users with administrator rights, it is also very susceptible to security problems.

Reading your question immediately starts me to think of an [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)-like1 database system, although it is a highly controversial scheme to use in a relational database system like mysql, to use on any system actually...

A few problems that come to mind (most points apply to EAV too btw)

- **You will lose any logical structure**

  As any type of data can be linked to any type of entity, so - in your database at least - there is no logical relation between your attributes (or columns in your case) and your entities (tables in your case), other then just being present.
- **Very, very hard to maintain**

  If your tables grow, what columns should be indexed? How would you prevent from someone ignorant - and as you say they are by default - adding 200 columns to a table? Numerous other problems can be summed up here...
- **What about restrictions?**

  How are you gonna decide who is allowed to add/delete/edit what columns? And how are you force them to choose the right column-type? Or when a table is added: what should be the (coumpound) primary key? Remember: your administrators are ignorant. I guess this would rise the need for meta-tables, holding this kind of information. Are you sure you want to write all the logic for this? And are you sure you are wanting to keep track of bugs etc, bugs which will most probably allow your system to collapse like a card-house?
- **It smells like an excel sheet...**

  Without functions that is, but still. So why not send your administrators a link to google docs? ;)

No really, it sounds like a very bad idea...

Please post your full user-case, I'm quite sure we can think of a better solution then adding columns and adding tables to a database.

Comment: Please are you saying is a bad idea to allow administrators have such an access to add columns and tables to a database?

Comment: Basically: yes. IMO only those who have knowledge of the underlying system itself, in this case, (my)sql should be allowed to alter the database structure... There are numerous other options to allow administrators to handle (possibly) complex and different types of data

Comment: Oh ok,But lets take a situation where you have created a database with tables having two columns(ID and Name) and later the administrator who is ignorant of mysql and php wants to add say Age to the table, how do you solve such a situation.

Comment: Well, if you're building a CRM-like application, you might want to think about EAV. But most of the times adding such a column also involves changing the way how data is displayed on the front-end, and thus it needs interference from a webmaster anyway.

Please explain a little bit more about your specific problem, that's the only way we can help you consider your options ;)